# Customized tables with different sized rows and columns

Tags: tables, multicol

I wish to create a table with different sized rows and columns like here:[image]
I tried the following code:

```
\begin{document}
\usepackage{multicol}

\maketitle
\begin{table}[ht]

\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
\multicolumn {3}{c}\\
 1.Project Title :&\vline DST No.:\\
 \hline
   PI (Name and Address): &\vline Date of Birth:\\
  3. Co-PI(Name and Address)&\vline Date of Birth:\\
  \hline

  
 \multicolumn{3}{c}\\
  4.Broad area of Research: \\
  4.1 Sub Area: \\
  5. Approved Objective of the proposal: \\ 
  \hline
  \multicolumn{3}{c}
  \hline
   Date of Start:  &\vline\\ 
   
   Date of completion: &\vline Expenditure as on :\\
   \hline

   \end{tabular}

   \end{table}
   \end{document}
```

I am getting several errors in the final compilation, like misplaced \cr, misplaced alignment, etc. How should I proceed to build such a kind of table? I do not know if we can build such a table in open office doc, apart from latex also. Any hints? Thanks beforehand.

Comment: You've created a two column table, but you're trying to use `\multicolumn{3}`. Try using `{2}` instead. And you should only need the `\multicolumn` for the middle part of the table.

Comment: @AlanMunn still got error. In addition, you can see that I want only one column after the third row. How should I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many issues with the code you've shown, especially your use of `\multicolumn`. The `multicol` package is not needed for this command which is a command for tabular material; the `multicol` package is for making multicolumn text outside of a table.

For this sort of table you don't want to use a `table` environment. The `table` environment turns its contents into a floating object which is inappropriate here.

Basically for this table you need a two column format with fixed width columns and then a `\multicolumn` spanning the two columns for the centre panel of the table. I've used the `array` package to allow formatting commands to be included in the column specifications to add vertical space to the cells.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}

\setlength{\extrarowheight}{3pt}
\begin{tabular}{|p{4in}<{\vspace{.25in}}|p{2in}|}

\hline
 1.Project Title : & DST No.:\\
 \hline
   PI (Name and Address):  & Date of Birth:\\
  3. Co-PI(Name and Address) & Date of Birth:\\
  \hline  
 \multicolumn{2}{|p{6in}<{\vspace{5in}}|}{
  4. Broad area of Research: 
  
  4.1 Sub Area: 
  
  5. Approved Objective of the proposal: 
 }\\
  \hline
   Date of Start:  & \\
   
   Date of completion: & Expenditure as on :\\
   \hline

\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: that was great! helped a lot. But, is there a way to merge two columns in a table?

Comment: @vidyarthi Yes, that's what `\multicolumn` does (as in the centre part of your form).